# В каком ряду не все слова образованы одинаковым способом?

Tags: морфемика

Вопрос из добровольной аттестации (для учителей школы) по русскому языку (Армения).

**В каком ряду не все слова образованы одинаковым способом?**

1. Проректор, доисторический, вздернуть, некстати.
2. Возвратиться, вдуматься, достучаться, завраться.
3. Неверие, побережье, досиня, сотрудник.
4. Сладость, горошина, шумный, светлеть.

Скажу сразу: с ответом я не согласен. А какой вариант выберете вы?

Comment: Странно, в тексте скобки, а здесь точка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы выбрал **второй** ряд.

См.:

возвратить-**ся**,

**в**-думать-**ся**,

**до**-стучать-**ся**,

**за**-врать-**ся**.

Первое слово образовано **суффиксальным** способом, остальные – **приставочно-суффиксальным**.

Comment: В ответах тоже второй ряд. Но: не/вер/и/е - приставочно-суффиксальный способ; побережье - приставочным способом, досиня - приставочно-суффиксальный.

Comment: **Побережье** образовано не приставочным способом, а **приставочно-суффиксальным**, как и все слова в третьем ряду. См.: **по**-береж-**j**-е.

Comment: Здесь суффикс ье?

Comment: Нет, здесь суффикс «j» (йот), скрытый в окончании «е»: побережь[/**j**/э]

Comment: В морфемных словарях суффикс вообще не представлен.

Comment: У Тихонова есть: 
по/бере́жь/е [й/э].
   http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/dictionary/morphemic-orthographic/fc/slovar-207-5.htm#zag-54201

Comment: И все же:графически это суффикс ие/ье? Как например:  заречье, подножье. Суффикс -ие (-ье) — существительные со значением места: Или: сердие, изобилие, раздоль[j]е; суффикс -и-е (-ьj-е) — существительные со значением признака,

Comment: Можно и так говорить, но при этом не упускать из виду, что эти «-ие (-ье)»  включают в себя не только суффикс, но и окончание. Более понятен, по-моему, другой подход. См., к примеру, Литневскую: 

«Слово же _поднебесье_ содержит в своем составе суффикс _-j-_, который на буквенном уровне никак не выражен: _**под-неб-есь-j-е**_.»


http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm

Comment: Спасибо, понятно!